# When to use AJAX and avoid the refresh / reload page issue

Tags: ajax, refresh, reload

I am enjoying the experience of learning AJAX but I'm picking up articles with mixed reviews of when to actually use it.

My question is - what do you do if a person refreshes a page?  I'm losing all my ajax information that was processed and returned, and placed into the div and span placeholders.

How do you keep that status or ajax call or does it all reset???  Maybe I'm not supposed to do ajax on a login page or is there a way to preserve the settings without lots of cookies being set?

I have code but it's so much to fit in the window, I thought it may be better to ask if there is such a way to preserve all that ajax work or must it be wiped out by reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most AJAX apps I've seen don't handle a page refresh other than resetting the entire application state.  Try it with Yahoo or most sites.

Back and forward clicks also wreak havoc (though HTML5 does allow trapping those events).  `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` might be useful too.

Typically the AJAX app tries to prevent the action with a pop up message to warn the user (for example: Are you sure you want to do that Dave?)

To recover from a refresh, you would probably want to save your app state on the server if anything, and only save a pointer to the session id in a cookie.

Comment: so it's best to just use AJAX for a complex form that might involve lots of dropdowns and data being instantly calculated... not necessarily a simple login for correct?

Comment: Maybe, though AJAX code can be written very similarly to back-end server code too.  You could put a code fork at the top that checked the log in state.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at using `location.hash` or `html5 pushstate` to keep the data between refreshes.

HTML5 push state changes the URL in the location bar of your browser, without reloading a whole new page. This makes it so you can give each stage or state it's own permalink, but it's not supported by old browsers.

- http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate
- https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Location.hash does the same thing but changes the hash of a URL, eg `http://server.com/location#hash` and you can then use various libraries to read this hash value and change the page. This has the advantage of being compatible with older browsers.

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/docs/files/jquery-ba-hashchange-js.html

Answer (score 0):

On a normal reload .It is obvious that what ever data you got in the page will be wiped out . Nut if you really wanne store some thing than make a cookie in the `success function` of a ajax call .

Also you need to decide where to use ajax or not  . Becuase ajax main purpose it to keep getting data  on the same page but without doing a refresh . Becuase on refresh old data will be gone .

I hope you got your  answer .